# How can i find device unique id in ios (not UUID)

Tags: ios

Please can anyone help me to find unique id of ios device rather than UUID.Because UUID got changed when i reset the phone

Comment: may i know for what you use unique id?

Comment: if you want to create uniqueId rather than UUID so you have to create manual logic.

Comment: i need unique id for all the devices which we have in the organization and which are using for testing.so for security and for information purpose that where the devices and current owner of it we are storing the information  about devices so that's why we need it

Comment: sorry you can not get any unique id. because all the unique id and also device token changed when device reset.

Comment: so you can do that via recording every time new entry of the uuid but how that you have to decide

Comment: If i  make separate provision profile for it for the device token.because device token not changes every time on reset but i have confusion that is it will be changed when i will update the os.

Comment: sorry that i don't know now i can't help you.

Comment: No problem thanks for sharing your knowledge.